# DSum with date criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to count the number of shifts worked by people over the last twelve months. I want to use `DateSerial`. My code works if I input an actual date, not `DateSerial`. I tested my code by changing `DateSerial` to return a date other than twelve months ago but my code always gives the figure for the sum of all data - going back more than twelve months. So it ignores MyDt. Where am I going wrong?

```
Public Function Shifts() As Integer

Dim MyDt As Date

MyDt = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 12, 1) - 1

Shifts = DSum("Shifts", "tblWorkNew", "GP = " & GPLookup & "And Month > #31/10/2012#")  'This works for any date.
Shifts = DSum("Shifts", "tblWorkNew", "GP = " & GPLookup & "And Month > " & MyDt) 'This only gives all data, i.e. ignores MyDt

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyDt` is Date/Time, but you include it as a string in your `DSum` criteria argument.  So transform the value to a string which the db engine recognizes as the date you intend.

```vb
Shifts = DSum("Shifts", "tblWorkNew", _
    "GP = " & GPLookup & _
    " And [Month] > " & Format(MyDt, "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#"))
```

I added a space before `And` because it looked like there was one missing.  I assumed `Month` is the name of a field in your `tblWorkNew` table, so enclosed it in square brackets to inform the db engine you don't want the `Month()` function instead.